# HTML/CSS Heigth 100% and px

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, height

'm building a site, and I have a top bar that sticks to the top of the screen, then below I have an Iframe and that's all. The problem is as follows, my top bar is 50px height, and i want the iFrame to be 100%-50px. Is there a way to do it in CSS? If not, how would you do it with javascript? (I don't know the functions to get the window size).

|-------------top bar-------------| 50px
|***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**| 100%-50px
\iframe
\iframe
\
\
\
\

Comment: apply  'margin-top' or 'position:relative;top:some_value_' to frame

Comment: So, do you have any questions on the 4 answers you have received?

Comment: check my edit, i completely forgot about `box-sizing`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is not need for javascript.
make the iframe height 100%; and add a padding to the top to offset the top bar.

```
 iframe{  padding-top:50px; height:100%; 
          box-sizing:border-box; moz-box-sizing:border-box }
```

the key attribute is `box-sizing`. making the element height `100%` will do just as its suppose to do, but any other padding will just add to the size of the height or width depending on how you pad it.  but if you make the `box-sizing` `border-box`, this will force the browser not to add to the height or width but instead take or subtract (i.e. *'100%-50px'*) from the height or width.

so long story short, `box-sizing` is the missing feature in your css. **NO NEED FOR JAVASCRIPT**, that would just be overkill.

NOTE: this works for all browsers

Comment: and then the annoying scroll bars pop in to our beautiful website. -_-

Comment: doesn't matter thats the effect he wants, due to the padding on the iframe, no content in it will be overlapped by the top bar

Comment: Thanks! it worked, I only had to put padding-bottom instead of top!

Comment: well for each their own.. you should accept the answer so the question can be considered answered

Answer (score 0):

There's a way!

Use this function in CSS: `min-height: calc(100% - 50px);`

The `min-height` here will do the trick. Without that `min` it will take that as a `max-height` and will **not** expands its height until its content reaches `100% - 50px`.

[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Dmtm7/)

Comment: this doesn't work in IE 8 or earlier, safari 6 or earlier... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Comment: would you not want it to be `max-height` as well as ^

Answer (score 0):

Use this:-

```
#iframeid{
height: -moz-calc(100% -  50px);
height: -webkit-calc(100% - 50px);
height: calc(100% - 50px);
}
```

Comment: Yes but its supported by IE9 and later version which is mostly used today.

Comment: you shouldn't build apps based off your opinion. take a look http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-201301-201306-bar

Comment: @jay well, u r right. But i am surprised to know that IE 9 has surpassed chrome :O ???

Comment: @Vivek microsoft is a monopoly, every new computer with windows have IE 8, 9, or 10 pre installed. generally when we look at browser stats made from a developers website, its biased bc we as developers use chrome almost exclusively

Answer (score 0):

give your iframe in css a padding-top: 50px

like this

```
iframe {
    padding-top:50px;
 }
```

or you can give your iframe a class and define the padding-top: 50px; in there

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `box-sizing` and `padding`

here is what i have come up with

```
<div id="top-bar"></div>
<iframe src="http://www.jsfiddle.net" frameborder="0"></iframe>

*{
    box-sizing:border-box; // box sizing allows us to add 50px padding to the iframe
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; // Without effecting the size
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    margin:0;
}

#top-bar{
    height:50px; // Height of top bar
    position:fixed; // Fixed
    background:skyblue;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}

iframe{
    padding-top:50px; // Height of top bar
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
}

body, html{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden; // There was like 10px of empty overflow at the bottom 
    // i will find out why
}
```

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zqm2F/)

Give me a few mins and ill explain everything.

This is the only way i can think of that will work in IE8+ 
Otherwise it's javascript